# How can I take specific data from an API and export it without writing the data to a file?

Tags: python, xml, api, python-requests

I'm new to Python and using APIs and would love some help!

Using the URL: http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries?format=xml
I want to gather each country's "iso2Code" and "name".
I want to be able to output the data in a cleaner XML file format or an array (but would love the knowledge on how to do both!).

I can currently write it to a file and make use of it there, but I am trying to sort it without that extra step.

I haven't got much so far at all, but here it is:

```
import requests

url = ("http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries?format=xml")

r = requests.get(url)

with open(('testcase.xml'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.text)

test = r.text
print(test)
```

[This is the data I receive upon printing. I want to gather the first two parts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCZtV.png)

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: So you want to write it to a different kind of file?

Comment: @SuperStew I want to write it to an XML, but only taking certain components from the first file

Comment: Have you looked at the XML library? And are you set on xml for a particular reason?

Comment: @SuperStew Not necessarily, I'm just trying to learn how to do it that was is all!

Comment: Fair enough. I don't use the xml stuff if I can avoid it, but this should get you pointed in the right direction https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html. If this is just an exercise, I would suggest also learning how to work with JSON data. In general, it seems to be preferred to xml most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML from complex types to simpler types for your specific needs such as extracting only *iso2Code* and *name*.

Python's `lxml` module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. However, because is XSLT is portable you don't need `lxml` but can call other programs like Linux/Mac's dedicated XSLT processor: [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html).

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:wb="http://www.worldbank.org"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="wb">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/wb:countries">
     <countries>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="wb:country"/>
     </countries>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wb:country">
     <country>
       <iso2Code><xsl:value-of select="wb:iso2Code"/></iso2Code>
       <name><xsl:value-of select="wb:name"/></name>
     </country>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(using lxml)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries?format=xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLT_Script.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE
transformer = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transformer(doc)

# PRINT TO SCREEN
print(result)

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(result)
```

**Python** *(command line call to Unix's xsltproc)*

```
import requests as rq
from subprocess import Popen

url = "http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries?format=xml"
r = rq.get(url)

with open('Input.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)              # NOTICE .text NOT USED

proc = Popen(['xsltproc -o Output.xml XSLT_Script.xsl Input.xml'], 
             shell=True, cwd='/path/to/working/directory',
             stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<countries>
  <country>
    <iso2Code>AW</iso2Code>
    <name>Aruba</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso2Code>AF</iso2Code>
    <name>Afghanistan</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso2Code>A9</iso2Code>
    <name>Africa</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso2Code>AO</iso2Code>
    <name>Angola</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso2Code>AL</iso2Code>
    <name>Albania</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso2Code>AD</iso2Code>
    <name>Andorra</name>
  </country>
...
</countries>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions (re) to find strings with findall in the XML and then save the results into a pandas dataframe.

Like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

url = ("http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries?format=xml")

r = requests.get(url)

with open(('testcase.xml'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.text)

test = r.text

# Parse through string and capture ISO and name
country_iso = re.findall(r"iso2Code>(.*)</wb:iso2Code",test)
country_name = re.findall(r"name>(.*)</wb:name",test)

# store in pandas dataframes, then concatenate them into one
country_iso_df = pd.DataFrame(country_iso, columns=['ISO'])
country_name_df = pd.DataFrame(country_name, columns=['Name'])
output_df = pd.concat([country_iso_df, country_name_df], axis=1)

# print then output to csv
output_df
output_df.to_csv("insert path here")
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realise it was such a faux pas!